# Getting Started with Algorithm Trading

Tags: trading, markets

I was curious if it is feasible and worth my time/money to build a trading platform using external APIs and libraries or is it easier to use something like TD Ameritrade. In other words, are there any quantifiable upsets, risk mitigation, or arbitrage opportunities associated with building my own trading platform and using my own algorithms to execute buy/sell orders. This may be the wrong group to ask this question.

Comment: If the time and effort that you put in to create this is going to result in a product that generates better trading profits or the eventual  sale of this product then go for it.  If it's just going to be redundant, why bother?

Comment: FYI with TD, you are going to need a big cash account in order to use their API.

Comment: I a big cash account in my Paypal/bank or a big cash account in TD?

Comment: @CodyRutscher you need at least $250k last I checked in TD.

Comment: Would the member voting to reopen care to share their thoughts? No edit since posting, as it stands, it’s off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unfortunately absolutely, totally, inconceivable this could ever amount to anything.

Best course of action: first get $20,000 you don't need, consider it a "college fee".  Put it in a trading account and learn to trade. Once the money is gone, start over.

With luck you will only have to do this 4 or 5 times until you have a basic feel for markets and trading.

> arbitrage opportunities...

It would *literally* be easier to say

> "I notice Boeing make money building 747s. Could I build one and compete and make lots of money?"

The companies that run algos to arbitrage the market literally deal with technical issues ***such as the speed of light*** on their software-hardware systems to eke out fractional wins.

You'd need $20 million annually ***just to hire a few basic engineers at this level*** to even vaguely get started in the game.